# Plot ratio of two histograms from the same variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this minimal example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(lab1 = c(rep("no", 10), rep("yes", 20)),
                 var1 = c(3,6,3,3,3,4,5,6,3,6,2,3,4,3,2,3,9,9,8,7,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,6,5,1)
                )
```

From this we can easily plot a histgram like:

```
 p <- ggplot(df,
             aes_string(x = 'var1', fill = 'lab1')) + 
             geom_histogram(position = 'dodge', bins = 20)
```

What I would like to do now is to add a line plot on top of it indicating the percentage of "no" counts (100*no/(yes+no)) for every bin (same bin size as for the histogram). This percentage should then be shown on a secondary axis.

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df_sum <- df %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  summarize(no_pct = 100 * sum(lab1 == "no") / n())

p <- ggplot(df,
            aes(x = var1, fill = lab1)) +
  geom_histogram(position = 'dodge', bins = 20) +
  geom_line(data = df_sum, aes(var1, no_pct / 10), inherit.aes = F) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = ~ . * 10)
p
```

[image]

Edit: added alternative binning

You might consider doing the binning upstream of ggplot to make it easier to calculate summary stats for them:

```
library(dplyr)
binwidth = 1

# Count how many of each lab1 within each bin of var1
df_bin <- df %>%
  count(var1 = floor(var1/binwidth)*binwidth, lab1)

# Get "no" share within each bin
df_sum <- df_bin %>%
  group_by(var1) %>%
  summarize(no_pct = 100 * sum(n * (lab1 == "no")) / sum(n))

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df_bin, aes(var1, n, fill = lab1),
           position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  geom_line(data = df_sum, aes(var1, no_pct / 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = ~ . * 10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works perfectly for data where "yes" and "no" can be summed up on the exact same value. However, if I changed the binsize, let's say to 5 this would not be valid anymore. Would it be possible to account for the bin size somehow?

Comment: Added manual binning. There's probably a way to get the binned stats within the ggplot call, but I bet it would be pretty advanced.